# VirtualBox networking modes for simulating a firewall

Tags: networking, virtualbox

This is probably a very simple question to an expert but I can't figure it out. I have the assignment of simulating(using virtual machines) a Firewall(PfSense) and filtering the transmitted data to a machine behind it, so I chose VirtualBox as my VMM and the first thing I studied were [networking modes](https://www.nakivo.com/blog/virtualbox-network-setting-guide/) of it. Then I tried to plan what networking modes I needed.

I use two VMs(one for PfSense and another one for an arbitrary OS, say Ubuntu; I'll call them PVM and UVM), but to me none of those modes sound proper for this scenario. For example:

```
UVM -> internal mode (a network adapter set on internal mode)
```

Problem -> According to the linked article, internal mode means NO ACCESS to the internet(external world), so I won't be able to test the firewall at all.

```
UVM -> host-only
```

Problem -> the same problem as above(no internet access). It's for inter-VM interactions and connections between the host and VMs in both ways.

```
UVM -> NAT
```

Problem -> The UVM will be isolated from the PVM in this mode. So the UVM will have its own independent connection to the internet(thus still no firewall on the way). Of course there's a "Port-Forwarding" option when using NAT, but it does the port-forwarding between the host OS and the VM and not between VMs.

```
UVM -> Bridged
```

Problem -> Same problem as the previous one (Isolated&independent VMs).

```
UVM -> NAT-Network
```

Problem -> Although UVM won't be isolated from the PVM anymore, the internet connection is still accessed through the VirtualBox NAT engine and not through another VM.

So afterwards, I read other articles such as [here](https://protegewiki.stanford.edu/wiki/Testing_Firewalls_and_Web_Proxies) and some Q&As. They mostly suggest that the UVMs must be in an internal network...! but it doesn't make sense as I explained above. Assuming I set two network adapters on the PVM: one NAT(toward internet) and one internal(toward internal network) on the PVM. So how would the UVM be able to send/receive any packets from the internet?

Comment: You simply need two network interfaces for your firewall and one for your "client". Connect your client in a way that is has to pass through your firewall and your firewall will have one internal and external interface.

Comment: Thank you. "Connect your client in a way that is has to pass through your firewall" --> that's exactly my question, none of the explanations of these modes seem to be that...

Comment: Yes, because it's a client configuration. You could isolate your client but you won't be able to force him to do anything in order to get him to use the firewall/router as a hop. You will have to configure your client accordingly. E.g. on your internal network you would use ... the internal mode in order to not have the ability to use the internet. So only if your client does pass through the firewall/router it would be able to use the internet.

Comment: @Seth Thank you a lot for your kind attention and response to my question.